# Exact type of QDBusArgument

Tags: qt, qdbus

Using `currentType()` I can get the `ElementType` of a `QDBusArgument`. That is a very unprecise information that tells me if it is an array, a basic type etc. I could not find a way to dig deeper. E.g. if it is a basic type... which exactly? Short? Int?

Is it possible to get the exact type of a QDBusArgument for debugging purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like if you convert a primitive type `QDBusArgument` to a `QVariant`, it will contain the exact type of the argument ([1](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdbusargument.html#asVariant)). You can then use `QVariant::type()` or `QVariant::typeName()` to get the variant `QMetaType` or a human-readable value:

```
QDBusArgument argument;
qDebug() << argument.asVariant().typeName();
```

Comment: It works in such way only for basic types (as already stated in documentation you referenced). Unfortunately there are no way to get user-defined meta typeId, registered with qDBusRegisterMetaType<T>(). At least, I didn't found yet. Furthermore, it makes qdbus_cast<Type>(...) useless...